# How to cast the Object[] elements with the specific field types of DTO when dealing with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: jpa, reflection, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I got the results using JPA Query like below:

```
String query = "Select dataId, dataName, dataValue, datadesc From Data";
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(10);
List<Object[]> dataList = q.getResultList();
```

Please not that, I don't want to select all fields like "Select d From Data d". I will select fields like following: 
"dataId, dataName", "dataId, dataName, datadesc "

I need to loop through dataList above and typecast each element based on field type:

My Data entity class like below:

```
public class Data{
  private Long permitId;
  private String permitNumber;
  private Date permitDate;
}
```

I did casting as below:

```
for (Object[] object : dataList) {
    Data d = new Data();
    d.setDataId((Long)object[0]);
    d.setDataName((String)object[1]);
    ...
}
```

But I would like to do this casting as dynamic:

```
for (Object[] object : dataList) {
    Data d = new Data();
    **for (Field field : Data.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (field.getName().equals("dataId")) {
        d.setDataId(**(field.getType())**object[0]);
    }
    if (field.getName().equals("dataName")) {
        d.setDataName(**(field.getType())**object[1]);
    }**
    ...
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Comment: I really have no idea why you would want to convert the concise, clear, simple, fast code of the first snippet into the longer, unclear, complex, slower code in the second one. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I have big table which consists of more than 50 columns. But client will request only for specific fields (Example: 10 fields). I just run the query to fetch only those 10 fields and give them to client. So instead of selecting all the fields, I am trying to fetch specific fields.

Comment: Do you mean that the client decides which field to query, and you want to return an object containing only those fields? If so, I would just return a List<Map<String, Object>>, where the keys are the field names, and the values are the field values. But yes, you can return a Data object, make sure it has a property matching every queryable field, and loop over the requested fields to generate a querydynamically, and populate the Data object using reflection.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please provide me the sample code for above solution based on my code above ?

Comment: No, you should try doing that by yourself. You're on the right track. But you need a loop over property names, otherwise the technique is useless. Start by writing the signature and the javadoc of the method you actually want to implement.

Comment: @JBNizet How can I know, which Object is of which type in Object[] ?

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. I just figured out the way as you suggested. "Select new map (dataId as dataId, dataNumber as dataNumber....) ..." its giving the expected one. one question, can't we avoid the " as aliasname" ? with out that I am not getting the property names.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DTO and use it inside the query, like:

```
String query = "Select new com.package.MyDto(dataId, dataName, dataValue, datadesc) From Data";
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(10);
List<MyDto> dataList = q.getResultList();
```

The MyDto class:

```
class MyDto {

    // fields

    MyDto(Long dataId, String dataName, Long dataValue, String datadesc) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
        this.dataName = dataName;
        this.dataValue= dataValue;
        this.datadesc= datadesc;
    }

    //getters
}
```